# Vue.js cannot use to <slot> to render the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slot

I just try to follow the example about the use of slot on the Vue official site. But it failed, I have made the code very short

parent component

```
<template>
  <subMenuTemp>
    <div class="text" >
      parent content
    </div>
  </subMenuTemp>
</template>

<script>
  import subMenuTemp from 'src/test/testChildren.vue'
  export default  {
    data() {
    },
    components: {
      subMenuTemp
    }
  }
</script>
```

children component another .vue file

```
<template>
  <div class="content">
      <slot>
        old content
      </slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>
```

although the code is very short, I still cannot find where is my fault

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include the two components in your `main.js` or some `.js` file that imports Vue. It should look like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import subMenuTemp from './test/testChildren.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App, subMenuTemp }
})
```

Comment: why should I need to import the parent component and children component in the main.js file? Does it mean that if I want to use `slot` , the parent and children component have to be loaded in the main.js. ( there is only two .js file in my project , the other is index.js which is used to register  the route url

Comment: Yes, you need to include the components in main.js.

Comment: No you don't, see https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oy15j?fontsize=14
If your Parent component imports the Child component it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register all components in the main file as pointed in other answers.

You just need to import the child component into the parent component just as you do.

See a here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oy15j?fontsize=14

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <parent-component message="Hello Vue !"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from "./components/ParentComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { ParentComponent }
};
</script>
```

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <child-component>
    <div class="test-parent">{{ message }}</div>
  </child-component>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  components: { ChildComponent },
  props: {
    message: String
  }
};
</script>
```

```
// ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <div class="test-child">
    <slot>default content</slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent"
};
</script>
```

```
<!-- Result -->
<div id="app">
  <div class="test-child">
    <div class="test-parent">Hello Vue !</div>
  </div>
</div>
```